# "The file can't be found" messages after sleep mode but cannot figure out what is causing it?

Tags: sleep-wake, error, monterey

Since I have updated to 12.3 on my MBP 13" M1, I receive these message boxes when my laptop wakes up from sleep. The weird thing is, it happens repetitively. When waking up in de morning, I have around 20 of these messages, when returning from for example lunch, I only have 3. The longer the laptop is assleep, the more messages I get.

I am only using Mac since 6 months or so, and I have no idea what can cause these messages. How can I remedy this or figure out what is causing this?

[image: Tens of these pop ups]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the issue; an update of BetterTouchTool (BTT) fixed it. This was apparently already an issue when 12.3 was in beta, but I just found the answer on a different medium. Posting it here, for whomever runs into the same.